# Jest + ES2015 import

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, jestjs

I am making an exercise with ES2015, Jest, React and I get this error:

```
TypeError: Property description must be an object: undefined
at defineProperties (native)
at Object.eval (<PROJECT>/node_modules/event-emitter/index.js:127:8)
```

After digging into it, I think it is related to the import of the nodeModule EventEmitter or by extending the class by it.

This is the code of the script file:

```
import EventEmitter from 'event-emitter';
import AppDispatcher from '../dispatcher/app-dispatcher';

import {
    ACTION_CURSOR_POSITION_CHANGED,
    ACTION_IS_DRAGGING_CHANGED
} from '../constants/actions';

let _draggingStoreInstance = null;

/**
 * DraggingStore class
 */
export default class DraggingStore extends EventEmitter
{
    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    constructor () {
    // ...
```

The source code of the test file looks like this:

```
import '../unmock/dragging-store.unmock.js';
import DraggingStore from '../../src/stores/dragging-store';

describe('Dragging Store', () => {
   let draggingStoreInstance = null;

   beforeEach(() => {
       draggingStoreInstance = DraggingStore.getInstance();
   });

   it('should be defined', () => {
       expect(DraggingStore).toBeDefined();
       expect(draggingStoreInstance).toBeDefined();
   });
});
```

I made an extra file for excluding mocks:

```
jest.dontMock('../../src/stores/dragging-store.js');
jest.dontMock('../../src/dispatcher/app-dispatcher.js');
jest.dontMock('../../src/constants/actions.js');
```

The code itself runs smoothly in the browser after compiling, but the test engine gives the error.

I added this in my package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
 "jest": {
    "scriptPreprocessor": "./node_modules/babel-jest",
    "unmockedModulePathPatterns": [
      "./node_modules/react"
    ],
    "collectCoverage": true,
    "testDirectoryName": "spec",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js"
    ],
    "collectCoverageOnlyFrom": {
        // All files to test
    }
  }
```

Does anyone have a clue how to get around the problem?
Thanks in advance...

Update: full source code can be found here: https://github.com/dejakob/unlease-chess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realize this is very late, but, a lot has changed in the time you have posted this question. With Jest v19+, and assuming you are using the latest version of Babel as well, you can follow the instructions here:

http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/webpack.html#using-with-webpack-2

since you are using modules, you will need to tell Babel to transpile them to commonjs `require`s so that they can be run in the node environment, which is how Jest works.

Comment: Jups, I posted this question a year ago and JEST itself heavily improved since. It's even set up in a default React Native project nowadays.